# Polymer - Don't load app until geolocation isn't set

Tags: polymer

I'm currently working on a webapp with the polymer-framework.

However, the whole application depends on the geolocation of the device. I'm setting the location in the app-globals file to use it globally, but it takes some time (around 500ms).

My question now is, how can I say to polymer that it should get to work, after the geolocation is set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the specific behavior you're looking for. A few cases:

1. Everything still loads when the page loads, including perhaps some app UI and you have a loading icon or similar to indicate that the app is still starting up while you're waiting for the location.
2. You don't want to show the app until you have the location. Perhaps you don't want the app resources to be loaded at this time either.
3. You don't even want Polymer to be loaded until you have the location.

There's a lot of options & they may depend on your app architecture a bit, but for a general structure:

1. show a loader icon on startup & just wait to populate any templates you have until location is set
2. perhaps keep the hidden attribute on your main app element until location is available &/or don't append the element to the DOM until this point (although with similar resource loading opportunity caveat as in 3 below).
3. you could wait to add polymer & related elements until location is available, but generally seems silly to do this since your app could be doing this work while the user is waiting for a location to be found.

If you've got a more specific need then more details are probably needed.